# Multi-color linear progress indicator in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I want to implement a progress bar like the one in the following image with Flutter.

[image: example_image]

Any packages or widgets available?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/step_progress_indicator. maybe you can refactor this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [flutter_colored_progress_indicators](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_colored_progress_indicators) package, it will achieve style near to the required one.

[image]

```
...
child: ColoredLinearProgressIndicator()
...
```

**Bonus:** You can check this packages rich [catalog](https://fluttergems.dev/indicators-loading-refresh-progress/) for Indicators: Loading, Refresh, Progress